# DB Insert User: Put plus (+) symbol instead of space. MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, replace

Is there a way to find to put a plus symbol instead of a space.

For Example:

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])&&isset($_POST['server'])) {
//Prevent SQL injections
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $server = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['server']);

//Check to see if email exists
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user, server FROM users WHERE user = '|$user' AND server = '$server'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) {

    die ("Name already in use with this server combination.");

}else {

    //query the data
    $query = "INSERT users SET user = '|$user', server = '$server'";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=data-insert.php?success=1&server='.$server.'&user='.$user.'">';

 }
}
```

I want $user to have a + symbol instead of space if they entered one. Possible or no?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use an HTTP Location header to perform redirects, not a *back* breaking meta refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple string replacement at `INSERT` time:

```
$query = "INSERT users SET user = REPLACE('|$user', ' ', '+'), server = '$server'";
```

Comment: what about $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user, server FROM users WHERE user = '|$user' AND server = '$server'"); Because it will be entered without the plus...

Comment: @David Meyer Then you should use the PHP `str_replace()` suggested by @AlienWebGuy rather than the MySQL `REPLACE()` or do  `WHERE user = REPLACE('|$user','+',' ')` to undo the plus

Answer (score 0):

Replace it:

```
$user = str_replace(' ','+',$user);
```

Check its existence:

```
if(strpos($user,' ') !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`+`, in a URL, means a space. If you want to pass a `+` symbol though a URI then you have to [encode it](https://www.php.net/url_encode) (which you should be doing to any data you insert into a URI anyway).